# Move Laravel project to hosting

Tags: php, laravel, host, virtualmin

I'm trying to move laravel project to host Virtualmin, I moved all folders in my Document root

```
HOME/
   MYPWD/
      APP/
      BOOTSTRAP/
      CONFIG/
      DATABASE/
      ....
      PUBLIC_HTML/
```

Inside PUBLIC_HTML I have the index.php with these lines:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

The login.php page work right, but after login, the browser return an error caused by recursively redirect. In logs I get this error:

> exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class
>   App\Http\Middleware\isNotAuth does not exist' in
>   /home/mypwd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734

I should change something else? Like namespace?

That's my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^3.2",
        "psr/log": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

While that's my .gitignore file:

```
/vendor
/node_modules
/public/storage
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
.env
```

Comment: It seems there is problem with the code nothing to do with server side. Can you post composer.json file content?

Comment: what is in your .gitignore file??

Comment: @SachinG. I posted it. I already run composer dump-autoload

Comment: did you fire a `composer dump-autoload`? whenever i deploy laravel to shared hosting, i'll modify it locally first and test it.

Comment: @BagusTesa locally works and also in my host work the login page, but when I login, I receveid in my logs file the error: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\Http\Middleware\isNotAuth does not exist' in /home/mypwd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734

Comment: no uh.. well, i just want to make sure it works locally first.. with it's changed `index.php`

Comment: Try to fix path its seems there is problem with it "psr-4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve myself the problem: server linux is case sensitive, so in Kernel.php I called middleware class with IsNotAuth, but filename was isNotAuth